# How to split string and assign as column and row in table

Tags: c#

I have a input strings example

```
str1 = ""Type":"#Microsoft.Azure","Email":"abc@tmail.com","DisplayName":"abc","Dpt":"home"";
str2 = ""Type":"#Microsoft.Azure","Email":"xyz@tmail.com","DisplayName":"xyz","Dpt":"home"";
```

In compileable form it looks like this:

```
string str = @"""Type"":""#Microsoft.Azure"",""Email"":""abc@tmail.com"",""DisplayName"":""abc"",""Dpt"":""home""";
```

Can i split on `","` delimiter and assign left to `":"` as columns and right to `":"` as rows in table.

Example:

[image: 1]

```
"Type"               "Email"        "DisplayName"   "Dpt"
"#Microsoft.Azure"  "abc@tmail.com"     "abc"       "home"
"#Microsoft.Azure"  "xyz@tmail.com"     "xyz"       "home"
```

i tried something like this

```
string str = ' "name":"abd","":""m"":"" '; 
string[] strS1 = str.split(','); 

foreach(string S1 in strS1){  

     string[] strS2 = str.split(':'); 

     foreach(string S2 in strS2){ 
         console.write(s2)  
     }  
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything? Put some effort. You can f.e. use Regex to parse values or parse char-by-char.

Comment: Do you want an output string or what ?

Comment: Just `Split`a second time on `:`.

Comment: Your strings don't have little curly braces (`{` and `}`) around them do they?

Comment: @john -  No braces

Comment: What does your data look like if one of the fields (e.g. DisplayName) includes a double quote (`"`)?

Comment: "Can i split on "," delimiter" yes you can. "Can i split on "," delimiter **and** assign left to ":" as columns and right to ":" as rows in table." No you cannot! you have to split each part again by `:` have you tried splitting it twice?

Comment: please edit your post to transform the strings into a ocmpileable form. Otherwise we are simply confused by it. We don't know whether you made a mistake or not

Comment: Please bare with me. This is my first C# program.    I tried something like  string str = ' "name":"abd","":""m"":"" '; string[] strS1 = str.split(','); foreach(string S1 in strS1){  string[] strS2 = str.split(':'); foreach(string S2 in strS2){ console.write(s2)  }  }

Comment: @VictorK Edit the question, and use ``` to markdown the code, so it could more readable.

Comment: @VictorK Tbh you just typed something, because C# is case-sensitive , and you are typing ``split`` instead of capital s ``Split()``, so it shows you the error immediately and it's not able to compile at all, same for the ``console.write`` should be ``Console.Write``.

Comment: @John - Value of displayname is "abc" and "xyz". Yes they are quotes

Comment: What I meant is, the data you have now is "abc" and "xyz", but if the display name were `abc","def`, (how) is the double quote escaped? For example, does it become `"abc"",""def"`? Or does it become `"abc\",\"def"`? Or is this scenario impossible?

Comment: Could you [edit] anominsed part of the CSV instead of those str1/str2? Just 2-3 line like you already have. Because Double triple escaping those in order to make the compiler stop crying is a pain. Really [mcve] should work a least and not cry on every single line. thx.

Comment: your solution will work with a minor change, as soon as you have changed it to a compileable form and change the second split `string[] strS2 = str.split(':');` to `string[] strS2 = S1.Split(':');`. Sorry mate, but all the effort that you put in your post could have been used to write a small programm that tests your algorithm. In the end you would have solved your problem on your own. Because the algorithm in your post is almost correct

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this : [Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DVNViH)

#### The Json Way.

You assume it's a Json.
Join the line with `},{`. Add a Starting `[{` and Ending `}]`. Bim, You are ready to go.

Deserilise to you custom type : *I ignored Type property here*

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CsvItem>>(myJSON);

public class CsvItem
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string Dpt { get; set; }
}
```

#### Your parsing way: String Split.

After the  `S1.Split(':')`, you end up with a small array the first value is the property name the second the value.
`Trim` the `"`, compare and assign.

```
if (strS2[0].Trim('"') == "Email") temp.Email = strS2[1].Trim('"');
if (strS2[0].Trim('"') == "DisplayName") temp.DisplayName = strS2[1].Trim('"');
if (strS2[0].Trim('"') == "Dpt") temp.Dpt = strS2[1].Trim('"');
```

#### Same thing in LinQ:

At this point it's not faster, easier to maintain, not even easier to read. It's just compact

```
lines
    .Select(x => x.Split(','))
    .Select(x =>
        new CsvItem
        {
            Email = x[1].Split(':')[1].Trim('"'),
            DisplayName = x[2].Split(':')[1].Trim('"'),
            Dpt = x[3].Split(':')[1].Trim('"')
        })
```

#### What's left?

Regex like : `"(\w+)":"(.+?)"`, could easy replace the split. With a more detailed regex you can catch only the value you need.

#### What solution in the end?

Depending on the quality of the file. If it's human generated and can containt error.
You way to handle the error: Do you reject the whole file in case of error? Do you return only the list of valid data? etc.

I will choose either Solution #1 or #2. #1 for sometime broken file. #2 for meticulous error handleing and debugging.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string inputCSV = @"""Type"":""#Microsoft.Azure"",""Email"":""abc@tmail.com"",""DisplayName"":""abc"",""Dpt"":""home""
""Type"":""#Microsoft.Azure"",""Email"":""xyz@tmail.com"",""DisplayName"":""xyz"",""Dpt"":""home""";

        // ReadAllLines mock
        string[] lines = inputCSV.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        { // The Json Way
            var bringJsonBack = "[\n{" + string.Join("},\n{", lines) + "}\n]";
            var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CsvItem>>(bringJsonBack);
            results.Dump();
        }

        { // Your working way
            var results = new List<CsvItem>();
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                var temp = new CsvItem();
                string[] strS1 = line.Split(',');
                foreach (string S1 in strS1)
                {
                    string[] strS2 = S1.Split(':');

                    // You have a part Before the : and one after we just string check to know what property we re on.
                    if (strS2[0].Trim('"') == "Email")
                    {
                        temp.Email = strS2[1].Trim('"');
                    }

                    if (strS2[0].Trim('"') == "DisplayName")
                    {
                        temp.DisplayName = strS2[1].Trim('"');
                    }

                    if (strS2[0].Trim('"') == "Dpt")
                    {
                        temp.Dpt = strS2[1].Trim('"');
                    }
                }
                results.Add(temp);
            }
            results.Dump();

        }

        { // LinQ Version of your algo.
            var results = lines
                                .Select(x => x.Split(','))
                                .Select(x =>
                                    new CsvItem
                                    {
                                        Email = x[1].Split(':')[1].Trim('"'),
                                        DisplayName = x[2].Split(':')[1].Trim('"'),
                                        Dpt = x[3].Split(':')[1].Trim('"')                                        
                                    })
                                .ToList();
            results.Dump();

        }

    }

    public class CsvItem
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string Dpt { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original string looks suspiciously like it was extracted from a JSON response. You should just deserialize the original JSON response directly into a DataTable with Newtonsoft.Json, ala:

```cs
//Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Data;

namespace Split_string_and_assign_as_table
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string json = @"[
    {
        ""Type"": ""#Microsoft.Azure"",
        ""Email"": ""abc@tmail.com"",
        ""DisplayName"": ""abc"",
        ""Dpt"": ""home""
    },
    {
        ""Type"": ""#Microsoft.Azure"",
        ""Email"": ""xyz@tmail.com"",
        ""DisplayName"": ""xyz"",
        ""Dpt"": ""home""
    }
]";
            var dataTable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(json);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We've already confirmed that it's not JSON. Certainly you could add curly braces to it to make it look like JSON, but without knowing if there's any escaping within values, and how it works (e.g. a display name of `Test"User`), it would be ill-advised to jump straight into that as a solution. Plus your code expects the data to be JSON already, which it isn't.

Comment: @John Sure, if you say so. The `"Type":"#Microsoft.Azure"` is a dead giveaway, though.

Comment: I asked OP if their string has curly braces around it, they said no. See the comments on the question.

Comment: @John Thank you, I did actually see the comments before I posted.

Comment: I don't know if its json or where it is coming from. I am given a csv file which has data in this fashion in single column without braces. Now i need to split into tabular format and load to db table

Comment: @Victor I'd recommend finding out if it started its life as JSON, and if you can get it in that format, since that would be much easier to work with.

Comment: @John - Thanks john. I will try to figure out and get the original file. I am not sure, but someone is taking it from Sharepoint Online and giving me a part of the file.

Comment: @Victor Could you post the original content you've got in the question? What you've posted currently wouldn't even be valid CSV format, so perhaps who/whatever's giving you the file is just "doing it wrong."

Comment: @FooMonkey - i have attached image of the excel file which i have(changed the content). As John mentioned i will try to get original file and try. Thanks